# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp at line 6

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, jsp

В общем, пишу код на одном компьютере. Работает. Делаю update через github, запускаю на другом. Вылезает ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp at line 6

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp at line 6

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp at line 6

3: <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
4: 
5: <html>
6: <jsp:include page="fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
7: <body>
8: <jsp:include page="fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
9: <div class="jumbotron">
```

Стектрейс:

```
12-Sep-2017 22:27:07.415 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/topjava] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp at line 6

3: <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
4: 
5: <html>
6: <jsp:include page="fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
7: <body>
8: <jsp:include page="fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
9: <div class="jumbotron">


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'app.title' for locale 'ru'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.fragments.headTag_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(headTag_jsp.java:182)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.fragments.headTag_jsp._jspService(headTag_jsp.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:526)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:887)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Как видим, проблема в якобы отсутствии сообщения для локали ru. Но она есть, есть и соответствующий тэг app.title=Подсчет калорий

Вот вся страница:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<html>
<jsp:include page="fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
<body>
<jsp:include page="fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <p/>

        <form method="post" action="users">
            <spring:message code="app.login"/>: <select name="userId">
            <option value="100000" selected>User</option>
            <option value="100001">Admin</option>
        </select>
            <button type="submit"><spring:message code="common.select"/></button>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="users"><spring:message code="user.title"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="meals"><spring:message code="meal.title"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<jsp:include page="fragments/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница подтягивает дополнительные страницы в качестве headTag и bodyHeader. Если я комментирую строчку 6, то та же ошибка в строчке 8.

headTag.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><spring:message code="app.title"/></title>
    <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/datatables/1.10.15/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/noty/3.1.0/lib/noty.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/icon-meal.png">

    <!--http://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/548473-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/datatables/1.10.15/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/datatables/1.10.15/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/noty/3.1.0/lib/noty.min.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

bodyHeader.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="meals" class="navbar-brand"><spring:message code="app.title"/></a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="users"><spring:message code="user.title"/></a>

                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как сконфигурирован messageSource?

Comment: Сергей, оказалось, не внёс системную переменную, которая была внесена в самом начале проекта на первый компьютер. Но Вам спасибо за оперативность и постоянное желание помочь.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов, напишите это в ответ - а то статистику отвеченности вопросов на сайте испортите))

Comment: Конечно, напишу. Я всё равно 2 дня ещё не могу принять свой ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, как выяснилось, при переносе проекта с одного компьютера на другой нельзя забывать про переменные окружения. В моём случае, переменная окружения была внесена в настройки `Tomcat`, в раздел `Startup/Connection`. Поэтому приложение и не могло найти папку `config` с локалями.

Также, если такая ошибка появляется в Debug-режиме, значит, Вы не прописали переменные окружения для Debug, это делается в `Tomcat -> Edit Configurations -> Startup/Connections -> Debug`.